# TextInpout autocorrect show opposite in ios [react native]

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

It's happened only in ios, i attached imag and you can see the behavior (autoCorrect for ios)

[image]

the TextInput style:

```
textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 24,
    writingDirection: 'rtl',
    top: 8,
    textAlign: "right",
},
```

- i tried all combination of rtl & ltr - right & left its text style, 
  so i thinking is not a problam with the text style

i attach package.json file in the project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.4.4",
    "@jumpn/react-native-jetifier": "^0.1.4",
    "@target-corp/react-native-svg-parser": "^1.0.6",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.21.1",
    "color": "^3.1.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "hat": "^0.0.3",
    "lottie-ios": "2.5.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "2.6.1",
    "mobx": "3.4.0",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "pushwoosh-react-native-plugin": "^5.13.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-circle-checkbox": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-device-info": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-email-link": "^1.6.2",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-pose": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.10",
    "react-native-rtl-layout": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-signalr": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-unique-id": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2",
    "rn-placeholder": "^2.0.0",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
```

Comment: Remove the `writingDirection` from the style here's a blog post from [facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html)

Comment: didn't work @fayeed

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Problem Cause

It could be that your device is using an RTL language (Arabic, etc.) and you explicit specified the `textAlign` and `wirtingDirection`.

---

### Quick Solution

You don't have to specify `textAlign` and `writingDirection` on your textInput styling.

---

### Localizing User Experience

If you want to localize the experience for your application to adapt RTL and LTR, follow along:

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native'   // ... import I18nManager along your other react native imports
```

change your `textInput` styling to reflect the following:

```
textInput: {
    top: 8,
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 24,
    alignSelf: 'center'
},
```

If you need to check the status of the phone either RTL or LTR you can check using the following:

```
    const isDeviceRTL = I18nManager.isRTL;
    if (isDeviceRTL) {
        // ... do something cause device is RTL
    } else {
        // ... do something else cause device is LTR
    }
```

Other way to use it in your styling is:

```
someTextStyle {
    textAlign: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'right' : 'ltr',
    writingDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
}
```

**Note: you will not need to use this last state actually because react detects text and if your device is RTL or LTR and adapts automatically, just wanted to show you a use case**

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot but it's didn't work for me...
i try all combinations of rtl-ltr & right-left in style, it's something else...

Comment: You are most welcome. I see can you please post your `package.json` file also the part of code where you are using this TextInput for better assessment. Thanks!

Comment: I attached in the post